# How to use operation inside proxy class as sync only?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

I followed [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/) to include WCF service into my ASP.NET core application.

It seems that Generated Reference.cs file automatically included Async operations. **Is it possible to make these operation sync only?** Either in Reference.cs using them on client side.?

Generated Reference.cs file looks like follows-

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     //
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SimpleServiceReference
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompositeType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SimpleService")]
    public partial class CompositeType : object
    {

        private bool BoolValueField;

        private string StringValueField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BoolValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BoolValueField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StringValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StringValueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService")]
    public interface ISimpleService
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataUsingDataContract", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISimpleService/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType composite);
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    public interface ISimpleServiceChannel : SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "0.5.0.0")]
    public partial class SimpleServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService>, SimpleServiceReference.ISimpleService
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public SimpleServiceClient() : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetDefaultBinding(), SimpleServiceClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), SimpleServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public SimpleServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(SimpleServiceReference.CompositeType composite)
        {
            return base.Channel.GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(composite);
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }

        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:49945/SimpleService.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
        {
            return SimpleServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService);
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
        {
            return SimpleServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService);
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {

            BasicHttpBinding_ISimpleService,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call async method synchronously and there are several ways to do this:

For `Task<T>` use:

```
var result = Task.Run(AsyncMethod).Result;  
// if the Task fails, GetResult() will just throw an `AggregateException`

// or use

var result AsyncMethod.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
// if the Task fails, GetResult() will just throw the exception caused directly
```

For `Task` (not `Task<T>`) use:

```
AsyncMethod.RunSynchronously();
```